# Is $f$ continuous if $f_n \to f$ point-wise (with additional info in post)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a question relating to a previous example.

We have:

- Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of differentiable functions on the interval $[0, 2]$
- Assume that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ on $[0, 2]$
- Assume there exists positive real $M$ st $\forall n,$ $ \sup_{x\in[0,2]}\{|f'_n(x)|\}=M$

Is the limit $f$ of $(f_n)$ continuous?

I know that there is a theorem that states that if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and each$f_n$ is continuous then f is continuous but I am unsure whether that is true here. Or should I be looking at this another way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem

Comment: Note that this is false without the last condition: consider $f_n(x) = \arctan(n(x - 1))$. The pointwise limit is $1$ for $x > 1$, $-1$ for $x < 1$, and $0$ for $x = 1$. Thus, your general approach cannot work, and you must do something that uses the last condition.

Comment: By last condition do you mean that $f_n \to f$ uniformly?

Comment: @user3482749 I guess if that condition ($f_n$ must converge uniformly to $f$) is required does that happen in this scenario? I'm fairly lost. I know Ascoli theorem allows us to get a sub sequence that converges to some continuous function but that seems different to what we want here.

Comment: Yes: if you had uniform convergence, then you would be done without the final condition by the theorem that you mention. Arzela-Ascoli lets you use the last get something uniformly convergent (necessarily to the same limit) using the last condition, so that you can apply that theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition on the derivatives implies that the sequence is equicontinuous because, by the Mean Value Theorem,

$$ |g(a) - g(b)| \le \sup_{c \in (a,b)}|g'(c)| |a - b|. $$

So then we can apply the [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Differentiable_functions) to conclude that there is a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Therefore, because $f$ is the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence, it must be continuous. This wouldn't necessarily be true if we didn't have equicontinuity.

Comment: Okay so originally we know that $(f_n)_{1}^{\infty}$ converges pointwise to $f.$ Then after applying Arzelia Thrm we get a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ that converges uniformly to a continuous function. How do we know that this continuous function is $f$?

Comment: @CHTM Every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, as noted, it follows that the convergence is uniform. But if all you want is to show that $f$ is continuous, that's completely trivial: $$|f(x)-f(y)|=\lim|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\le M|x-y|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Without using Arzelà–Ascoli:

Let $\varepsilon>0$, and by compactness, cover $[0,2]$ by finitely many $\varepsilon$-balls centered at $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. Fix $x\in[0,2]$; then there exists $x_j$, $1\leq j\leq n$ such that $x\in B_\varepsilon(x_j)$. By the triangle inequality:
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq|f_n(x)-f_n(x_j)|+|f_n(x_j)-f(x_j)|+|f(x_j)-f(x)|.$$
By the mean value theorem, $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_j)|\leq M|x-x_j|<M\varepsilon$. Choose $N_j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x_j)-f(x_j)|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N_j$ by pointwise convergence.

For the last term, we want to show that $|f(x_j)-f(x)|\leq M|x-x_j|$ as well. Note that:
$$\big||f(x_j)-f(x)|-|f_n(x_j)-f_n(x)|\big|\leq|f_n(x_j)-f(x_j)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$$
by the triangle inequality and for large enough $n$ by pointwise convergence. Hence:
$$|f(x_j)-f(x)|<\varepsilon+|f_n(x_j)-f_n(x)|\leq\varepsilon+M|x-x_j|,$$
and since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary we have $|f(x_j)-f(x)|\leq M|x-x_j|<M\varepsilon$. It follows that:
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon(1+2M).$$
Note that $N_j$ depends only on $x_j$, so choose $N=\max\{N_1,\ldots,N_n\}$. Then this $N$ works for each $x\in[0,2]$, so the convergence is uniform and *a fortiori* $f$ is continuous.